How do Icopy a program to the Startup folder in Visual Basic?
So, I am trying to develop a proof-of-concept antivirus that copies a launcher to startup using the Visual Basic Express runtime. However, you can't just use %appdata% to access the AppData folder like in a batchfile. What can I use instead?
I somewhat foolishly expected %appdata% to work, so I threw the following code at VB Express:
fso.CopyFile(Application.ExecutablePath, "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")

Using GetEnvironmentVariable:
fso.CopyFile(Application.ExecutablePath, Application.GetEnvironmentVariable("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")

